# How Can I Detect something from HTTP Response

Tags: bash

I'am Developing bash script can detect web application firewall from header tags but i can find example like my idea ?

Comment: what does your script do so far?

Answer (score 1):

To find the request headers from bash you can simply use `curl`. If you're on windows you'll want the new windows bash shell or cygwin to run it.

There are dozens more tricks you can play with curl to get whatever you want in whatever format you want, lots of SO questions on it to answer any questions you come up with.

```
curl --head www.google.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 02:07:00 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: NID=100=IoNzfnVsz_oaEwIQE182ysgVSHoZYRVKjTqSQ5GqKrz1ewxwav2ae5GPo_bx0apr39Pnn4yvM5RfsmQnJ_QFmllVwS34ts-bNrvkzDFIfaokkDTo1BXHDDI69duBn1f9kx4sXJ_rcCK28og6; expires=Fri, 06-Oct-2017 02:07:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Here's an example of getting response headers using `curl`:

```
curl -D - www.google.com


HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Thu, 06 Apr 2017 02:11:26 GMT
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
P3P: CP="This is not a P3P policy! See https://www.google.com/support/accounts/answer/151657?hl=en for more info."
Server: gws
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
Set-Cookie: NID=100=DrUalBDiHKiZkX0yETtowdWhEfjJy7ioPU0Fe7Wch9pbbYI8MeSbg8M42dHmwu-hKZmYUlnE7VIgLhJ_Zi6byG_PYpTu5s2KYUv9XjPeH-GfSOTSq22I2GnEqXZwhJv-Bdn0aYzCUugF9FHb3Q; expires=Fri, 06-Oct-2017 02:11:26 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
Accept-Ranges: none
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

<!doctype html><html itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en"><head><meta content="Search the world's information, including webpages, images, videos and more. Google has many special features to help you find exactly what you're looking for." name="description"><meta content="noodp" name="robots"><meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><meta content="/images/branding/googleg/1x/googleg_standard_color_128dp.png" itemprop=<cut the rest of the HTTP request>
```

Comment: no i what to detect like X-XSS-Protection Found or not from request using bash script

Comment: Can you explain in a little more detail what you're looking for, it's not clear yet.